# Add quotes to a list of words in a sentence in python using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6

I have a list of words like:

```
["apple", "orange", "plum"]
```

I would like to add quotes only to these words in a string :

```
Rita has apple  ----> Rita has "apple"
Sita has "apple" and plum ----> Sita has "apple" and "plum"
```

How can I achieve this in python using regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with an alternation pattern created by joining the words in the list. Enclose the alternation pattern in word boundary assertions `\b` so that it would only match whole words. Use negative lookbehind and lookahead to avoid matching words already enclosed in double quotes:

```
import re
words = ["apple", "orange", "plum"]
s = 'Sita has apple and "plum" and loves drinking snapple'
print(re.sub(r'\b(?!<")(%s)(?!")\b' % '|'.join(words), r'"\1"', s))
```

This outputs:

```
Sita has "apple" and "plum" and loves drinking snapple
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/Tf9Aka

Comment: This is a cool one liner, but what is an alternation pattern?

Comment: An alternation pattern is a pattern that merges several patterns with an alternation operator `|`. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html .

Comment: I'll have to do some reading, that's an interesting feature I haven't seen before

Comment: @C.Nivs: another interesting featuredused in this solution is called *zero length assertion* in this case visible as `\b`: as documentation of re module says: it matches boundary between `\w` and `\W`.

Comment: This looks good. But how do I handle the situation mentioned by Pault below?

What if the sentence was "Rita drinks apple flavored snapple?"

Comment: @user2728024 That's exactly what the word boundary assertion `\b` is for. It makes sure that the matches occur only at the boundaries of the words so `apple` would not match `snapple`.

Comment: @blhsing Makes sense but double quotes are not included? Sita has apple and "plum" is coming as Sita has "apple" and ""plum""

Comment: @user2728024 That's a new requirement that you should've put into the question. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution without using regex:

```
txt = "Sita has apple and plum"
words = ["apple", "orange", "plum"]
txt = " ".join(["\""+w+"\"" if w in words else w for w in txt.split()])
print (txt)

txt = "Rita drinks apple flavored snapple?"
txt = " ".join(["\""+w+"\"" if w in words else w for w in txt.split()])
print (txt)
```

Comment: What if the sentence was `"Rita drinks apple flavored snapple?"`

Answer (score 0):

`re.sub` can handle this for you nicely

```py
import re

mystr = "Rita has apple"
mylist = ["apple", "orange", "plum"]

for item in mylist:
    mystr = re.sub(item, '\"%s\"'%item, mystr)

print(mystr)
```